# Contar apenas novos regsitros no banco e apresentar como notificações

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Tenho a seguinte questão, preciso retornar em um painel que existem registros que não estão sendo mostrados na tela. Tipo tenho 10 registros sendo exibidos, são cadastrados mais 2 dai preciso mostrar uma notificação parecida com a do Facebook.

Num primeiro momento pensei em cadastrar os novos registro com um status e depois muda-lo quando o registro fosse carregado na tela até funcionou muito bem. O que gostaria de saber é se existe algo feito através do mysql mesmo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não há amigo, o controle tem que ser manual, com uma flag como vc fez ou inserindo esses novos IDs em uma tabela de controle com a mesma finalidade.

Comment: Que pena. Seria tão amigável. Vou ter que manter meu código com está então. Depois que otimizar ele posto aqui para ajudar alguém no futuro.